# What is the relation between plastic surgery and plastic?

Tags: etymology

Reading some books, I am wondering if there is any connection between plastic surgery and plastic itself?

One definition from OED seems to fit:

> (Of substances or materials) easily shaped or moulded:

Comment: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plastic) says of the adjectival usage: *Surgical sense of "remedying a deficiency of structure" is first recorded **1839** (in plastic surgery). Meaning "made of plastic" is from 1909.* They say the noun sense *solid substance that can be molded* dates from 1905. So the term ***plastic surgery*** long predates what you understand the word ***plastic*** to mean.

Comment: Plastic is an adjective.  Although it is sometimes used as a noun, shorthand for "plastic material".

Comment: I'm sure the same question has crossed everybody's minds at one point of our lives. So I quite like it, but perhaps you could have shown a little bit of research, looked up the word in a dictionary that type of thing. Just saying :)

Answer (score 4):

A quick look at [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=plastic+surgery&searchmode=none) tells us (emphasis mine):

> 1630s, "capable of shaping or molding," from Latin plasticus, from Greek plastikos "able to be molded, pertaining to molding, fit for molding," also in reference to the arts, from plastos "molded, formed," verbal adjective from plassein "to mold" (see plasma). **Surgical sense of "remedying a deficiency of structure" is first recorded 1839 (in plastic surgery)**. Meaning "made of plastic" is from 1909. Picked up in counterculture slang with meaning "false, superficial" (1963). Plastic explosive (n.) attested from 1894.

So the _plastic_in plastic surgery refers to *molding* the structure (of the body).

As for *plastic* to mean the stuff that your shopping bag, keyboard and throw-away-cups are made of, *plastic* there is basically a short form of *thermoplastic polymer*, as opposed to *thermoset polymer*, depending on whether the polymer can be (re)molded when heated. We commonly refer to all kinds of polymers as *plastic* in everyday language, regardless of whether they are thermoplastic or thermoset.

So, yes, there is a link, in both cases *plastic* refers to *molding*.

Comment: Very interesting. I suppose I had always assumed *plastic* was a modern coinage like *nylon*.